# Struct with file pointer of pointer in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm using this struct to deal with pointer of pointers:

```
typedef struct resources{
  FILE *file;
}Resources;
```

And this will close the file:

```
int resources_free(){
  fclose(resource->file);
  FREE(resource);
  return 0;
}
```

This fuction will add a new pointer of pointer to the struct:

```
int new_file_resource(FILE *file)){
  resource = malloc(sizeof(Resources));
  resource->file = malloc(sizeof(file));
  resource->file = *file;
  return 0;
}
```

But for some reason i get "in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 block".

Comment: That shouldn't compile, enable your warnings.

Comment: Warnings are enabled. Why shouldn't compile?

Comment: Why allocate the file pointer? Just copy the *pointer* and not the structure (which most likely will cause other problems).

Comment: don't dereference the file pointer when you assign it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` is already a pointer, you don't need to reserve space for it:

```
int new_file_resource(FILE *file)){
  resource = malloc(sizeof(TResources));
  resource->file = malloc(sizeof(file)); /* remove this line */
  resource->file = *file; /* should be resource->file = file; */
  return 0;
}
```

Also note that you `return 0` without checking the result of `malloc`, I suggest:

```
int new_file_resource(FILE *file)){
  resource = malloc(sizeof(TResources));
  if (resource) {
    resource->file = file;
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

> if i'm using multiple files i need to insert on struct "FILE
>   *file_one, *file_two"? Any way to do this dynamically?

You need a pointer to pointer:

```
#define NFILES 2
FILE **f;

f = malloc(sizeof(*f) * NFILES);
f[0] = fopen("a.txt", "r");
f[1] = fopen("b.txt", "r");
```

Comment: `resource->file = *file;` or `resource->file = file;` ??

Comment: @AlterMann if i'm using multiple files i need to insert on struct "FILE *file_one, *file_two"? Any way to do this dynamically?